# Как правильно перевести приложение на ASP.NET Core 3.1?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

Помогите разобраться, у меня есть приложение, написанное на MVC, стоит задача перенести его на Core 3.1. Проблема в том, что в mvc я наследовался от  `ApiController`

```
public class TestController : ApiController
```

а в Core 3.1 наследование идет от `ControllerBase`

```
public class TestController : ControllerBase
```

соответственно, я не могу обращаться к HttpRequestMessage/HttpResponseMessage из-за ошибки несоответствия типов,

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

так как в данном случаи `Request` - это HttpRequest.

Как можно решить данную проблему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте инструкцию [Migrate from ASP.NET Web API to ASP.NET Core](http://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/webapi?view=aspnetcore-6.0). Конкретно миграция контроллеров описана в этом пункте [Migrate models and controllers](http://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/webapi?view=aspnetcore-6.0#migrate-models-and-controllers).

Для конвертации HttpRequest в HttpRequestMessage можно использовать ответ отсюда [Convert Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpRequest to HttpRequestMessage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45759417/convert-microsoft-aspnetcore-http-httprequest-to-httprequestmessage), но предполагаю, что лучше мигрировать проект без дополнительных преобразований.